# Github workflow does not trigger on push for path based filtering

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a workflow where I need to run whenever there is a push to a Develop branch. I'm using path based filtering. Here is a snippet of the workflow

```
name: Push to XYZ

on:
  push:
    branches: [ Develop ]
    paths:
    - '!.github/**'

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Extract commit
        run: |
          echo "Sending commit $GITHUB_SHA for $GITHUB_REPOSITORY"
          curl -XPOST ......
```

So the idea is, on push to Develop(either directly or via a pull request) the workflow should run if the changes made are in folders or files other than the `.github` folder. This workflow is already pushed to Develop at `.github/workflows/file.yaml`. I take a branch out of Develop, make changes to files which are not in `.github` and raise a PR and merge it. But the workflow doesn't run

Am I missing something?

There is no syntax or indentation issue because I am able to manually trigger the workflow and it works fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is ti first add filter to allow for some folders and here it would be

```yaml
name: Push to XYZ

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
    paths:
    - '**'
    - '!.github/**'

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Extract commit
        run: |
          echo "Sending commit $GITHUB_SHA for $GITHUB_REPOSITORY"
```