# Github workflow excluding paths does not work

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I cannot get the Github workflow feature to exclude paths to work properly and could not find a similar problem on stack overflow. The most similar case is [Github workflow does not trigger on push for path based filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67717380/github-workflow-does-not-trigger-on-push-for-path-based-filtering) but it has not helped me.

I have the workflow for PRs below:

```
name: Build For PRs

on:
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, ready_for_review]
    paths:
      - 'src/**'
      - '!src/abc/**'
      - '!src/def/**'
      - '!src/ghi/**'
      - '!src/docker-compose*.yml'
      - '!**.md'
```

I want it to run on PR's when any file under "src" changes, except when one of the negative filters is a match.

Even changing a .md file triggers this WF. How can I achieve the logic above?

Comment: I suspect this might be related to the `types` subtype you informed together with the `paths` subtype. Does it work as expected if you remove the `types` list? As github actions work as `OR` condition on triggers, the workflow might trigger because of the `types` field and not the `paths` field.

Comment: @jessehouwing according to the documentation it is correct: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-including-paths

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution to this?

Comment: @ege no , if it is as Grzegorz said, it isn't designed for that kind of logic

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that excluding paths doesn't work as you want by design.

When all the path names match patterns in paths-ignore, the workflow will not run, but if you have at least one file that doesn't fall under negations - workflow will still run.

So there is no way to stop workflow by this feature the way you want to do - to stop workflow when at least 1 file belong to excluded list.

I would recommend filtering changed files and then stopping workflow if you find any files matching your criteria and use https://github.com/tj-actions/changed-files/ instead.
With that action you will be able to check if any files are fitting your criteria and then you just stop the workflow.
Unfortunately it will start full workflow, create a runner and execute workflow itself.